# Разница между записью А а1 = new A(), и А а1 = B()

Tags: java

У меня есть класс А и его дочерний класс B.

В чем разница между записью:

`А а1 = new A()`

и

```
А а1 = B()
```

Answer (score 6):

В обоих случаях вы объявляете переменную-ссылку типа `A`, но во втором случае вы присваиваете этой переменной ссылку на объект `B`.

При этом в обоих случаях вы можете вызывать только метода, описанные в классе `A`. Но, в случае, если в `B` их поведение переопределено, то во втором случае будет вызвана реализация из класса `B`, т.к. объект является именно `B`

Answer (score 3):

Во втором случае мы не сможем обращаться к уникальным методам класса B, но если какие-то методы переопределяют соответствующие из класса A, то будет работать именно переопределенная реализация.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь